# Conditional rendering with Rails depending on the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

Is there any proper way to detect the environment (development or production) in the application layout? Say, I don't want to render the GA code in my local sandbox.

In Django we use `{% if not debug %}{% include '_ga.html' %}{% endif %}`. What should I use in Rails? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use:

```
Rails.env.production?
#or
Rails.env.development?
#or
Rails.env.test?
```

See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class) for further information. So, you could do something like:

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <p>Dev Mode</p>
<% else %>
  <p>Production or test mode</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Aw, crap! I was checking the live website :-)

Comment: In order to do what? Rails.env is accessible from everywhere... I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: AH ok! :) I updated the answer anyway. It will help other people :)

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME. Saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize this question is old, but I just came across it looking for something similar myself. I think slightly better practice is not to ask "what environment am I in?" but rather to set configuration based on what you're trying to do. So if you wanted to add a custom debug footer in development, you could add the following to config/application.rb:

```
config.show_debug_footer = false
```

That sets the default behavior. Then in config/environments/development.rb you add:

```
config.show_debug_footer = true
```

And then in your code, where you need to change the behavior, you can check:

```
if Rails.configuration.show_debug_footer
  [...]
end
```

This is a very flexible way to have custom configuration that changes depending on your environment, and it keeps your code highly readable.

See [Rails documentation for Custom Configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration)